# Why the shared variable between Go routines won't updated

Tags: go

Why does the code snippet below print out `0`? However, `i` is correctly updated to `1` without the `for` loop.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var i uint64
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

**Solution 1**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "time"
)

func main() {

        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

        var i uint64
        ch := make(chan bool)
        go func() {
                for {
                        select {
                        case <-ch:
                                return
                        default:
                                i++
                        }
                }
        }()

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        ch <- true
        fmt.Println(i)
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "sync"
        "time"
)

func main() {

        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

        var i uint64
        var mx sync.Mutex
        go func() {
                for {
                        mx.Lock()
                        i++
                        mx.Unlock()
                }
        }()

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        mx.Lock()
        fmt.Println(i)
        mx.Unlock()
}
```

**Solution 3**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "sync/atomic"
        "time"
)

func main() {

        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

        var i uint64
        go func() {
                for {
                        atomic.AddUint64(&i, 1)
                        runtime.Gosched()
                }
        }()

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println(atomic.LoadUint64(&i))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition. The results are undefined.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var i uint64
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000a2010 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:18 +0x95

Previous write at 0x00c0000a2010 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:13 +0x4e

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/racer.go:11 +0x7a
==================
66259553
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

---

Reference: [Introducing the Go Race Detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

Answer (score 2):

Necessary reading for understanding - [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem)

> The Go memory model specifies the conditions under which reads of a variable in one goroutine can be guaranteed to observe values produced by writes to the same variable in a different goroutine.

Whenever you have 2 or more concurrent goroutines accessing same memory and one of them modifying memory (like `i++` in your example) you need to have some sort of synchronization: [mutex](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_8) or [channel](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7).

Something like this would be smallest modification necessary to your code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var (
        mu sync.Mutex
        i  uint64
    )

    go func() {
        for {
            mu.Lock()
            i++
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    mu.Lock()
    fmt.Println(i)
    mu.Unlock()
}
```

Oh and official [Advice](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_1):

> If you must read the rest of this document to understand the behavior of your program, you are being too clever. **Don't be clever.**

:) have fun

Answer (score 1):

Running this in the go playground, it times out, which slightly surprises me because, as Tarion says, the infinite for loop should be terminated upon exit from `main`. It seems that the go playground waits for all goroutines to complete before exiting. I imagine the reason you see 0 is to do with bad multithreading here. The for loop is continually updating `i` at the same time as `i` is read by main, and the results are unpredictable. I'm not sure what you are trying to demonstrate, but you would need a mutex here or a channel to read and update `i` safely on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "correctly" updated without the for loop, it's just randomly updated before you print it.

In go playgorund this ends with:

```
process took too long 
Program exited.
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/qKd-CdLt3uK

When starting the go routine the scheduler will decide when to switch the context between the execution of the go routine and the main function. In addition the go-routine is stopped when the main function ends.

What you want to do is some Synchronisation between your go routine and your main loop, since both are accessing a shared variable `i`.

Best practice here would be to use channels, sync.Mutex or sync.WaitGroup.

You can add some delay to your for loop, to give up some CPU for the main function:

```
go func() {
    for {
        i++
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}()
```

This will pint some value around 1000, but it's still not reliable.

Comment: It says `user  0m0.999s` via `time` command to run the original code snippet, so the `for` loop definitely keeps busy.

Comment: @Tarion I disagree with your first sentence. i is not "randomly" updated. OP allows a second to elapse, during which time i will be set to 1. It's not good design, but a second is a long time to allow a variable to be updated!